# Design View Blank for Windows Form in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have created a new Windows Form project in Visual Studio 2017.

I opened up the code editor for Form1.cs by right-clicking Form1.cs in the Solution Explorer and then clicking view code.

I then added in some code of my own so that Form1 is now as below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button button1;
        Button button2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Size = new Size(700, 500);
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;

            button1 = new Button();
            button1.Size = new Size(60, 40);
            button1.Location = new Point(30, 30);
            button1.Text = "Button 1";
            this.Controls.Add(button1);

            button2 = new Button();
            button2.Size = new Size(60, 40);
            button2.Location = new Point(100, 30);
            button2.Text = "Button 2";
            this.Controls.Add(button2);

            button1.Click += new EventHandler(AnyButton_Click);
            button2.Click += new EventHandler(AnyButton_Click);
        }

        private void AnyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked a button!");
        }
    }
```

When I run the project, Form1 is drawn exactly as expected and the button click events work fine.

However, the designer view (Form1.cs[Design]) is showing me a blank form.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem so that I can add my own code but it will be reflected in the design view?

Comment: It is expected behavior. The designer does not call the form constructor. You will not see any manually added controls until you run the application.

Comment: It is probably blank because you did not put anything on the form with the designer.  You instead opted to write the code by hand.  Which is fine, just not very productive.  Consider dropping those two buttons from the toolbox and setting the Size and FormBorderStyle properties with the Properties window.  Now it is no longer blank.

Comment: Okay, so you have to make a straight choice between handing coding controls and working with the designer?

Comment: You can do both. It is very common to add and remove controls at runtime. The designer could be cluttered to the point of uselessness if it showed you all the controls you might have on the form at any particular time.

Comment: You can do both, its just a quite complicated way of working. See my answer below, but I would recommend staying with the Form Designer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the messages guys. So if working with the designer is the way to go, do you need to know how to hand code anything at all for creating Windows Forms applications?

Comment: You still need to code all the logic which happens when you use the form. In your example that would be showing the textbox when you click any button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to make the buttons appear before runtime:

1. Add them using the drag and drop tool (called Form Designer) you get when you double-click the `MyUserControl.cs` file.
2. Add your code in the designer file (`MyUserControl.Designer.cs`) which is located by expanding `MyUserControl.cs`. I would **not** recommend this though, as you can quickly make a mess of things.

**Want to know more?**

As it can be seen in the image below, a Windows Form consists of three items:

1. A resource file (`MainWindow.resx`): Can contain resources used by that form, but this is hardly relevant in this topic.
2. A designer file (`MainWindows.Designer.cs`): The code version of the drag and drop designer. In this you can actually code your graphics, instead of using the graphical designer. I wouldn't recommend this though. If you like the idea of coding your UI, have a look at WPF instead.
3. The "Master" file (`MainWindow.cs`): This should be your main access to working with your GUI. Double click it, at you will open the GUI in the Visual Studio designer window. Here you can drag and drop items on to your form, and modify their properties (and events). You can also right click it and select "View Code" to go to the code behind the form. This is also where event code will be generated.

[image: Userform content]

Comment: Where is MyUserControl.Designer.cs file?

Comment: @VladP when you expand the "Master" file of a Windows Form, you will see it as the first option. Have a look at the extended guide, which I have added.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is useful.